# What dependencies to specify in CMakeLists.txt and which to specify in package.xml?

Tags: ros, package.xml, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Even after having read [this post](http://answers.ros.org/question/217475/cmakeliststxt-vs-packagexml/) regarding the difference between `CMakeLists.xml` and `package.xml` files (in the ROS context), I'm still not sure which dependencies should be specified in one or the other file.

I thought I needed to include (at least) in `find_package` (of the `CMakeLists.xml`) all the build dependencies (what about the other dependencies?) specified in the corresponding `package.xml` file, but this isn't the case, since I have a package where I'm specifying `rospkg` as a `<build_depend>` in `package.xml`, but if I also include `rospkg` in `find_packages` it gives me an error of the form

> Could not find a package configuration file provided by "rospkg" with any of the following names:

> ```
> rospkgConfig.cmake
> rospkg-config.cmake
> ```

On the other hand, a package like `rospy` also contains C++ code and I can include it in the `find_package` list.

The reason to have a `package.xml` and also a `CMakeLists.txt` is mainly due to, I guess, the need to support Python and C++ in ROS, but it's not very clear, again, which dependencies need to be specified in which files.

I checked the Github repository for `rospkg` and, indeed, it does not contain any C++ files (if I checked correctly), and thus it wouldn't make much sense to include `rospkg` in `CMakeLists.xml`...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260445/what-dependencies-to-specify-in-cmakelists.txt-and-which-to-specify-in-package.xml?/) by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 372 on 2017-04-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should specify ALL of your dependencies in the `package.xml`, since this is used to determine which packages are needed to build and run your package.

Since the `CMakeLists.txt` is used to build your messages and C++ code, you only need to specify your message and C++ dependencies in your `CMakeLists.txt`.

If you're writing python code, you should also write a `setup.py` where you specify your python package name and python dependencies.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2017-04-27**:
But by C++ dependencies do you mean all **non**-catkin (external) dependencies, or do you also mean catkin packages which contain C++ code (and thus I would need to check which catkin packages have C++ code)?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-04-27**:
By C++ dependencies, I mean any packages whose headers you `#include` in your code.

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2017-04-27**:
So, basically, also catkin packages which contain C++ code which I need to include.

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2017-04-27**:
You say I should specify Python dependencies in the `setup.py` file. I read around that `setup.py` file isn't used as for a general Python package, but just by `catkin`. Is this true? By Python dependencies do you mean also catkin packages or just external Python dependencies?